# Euclidean distance outside a Polygon (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, distance, buffer

I got some university coursework to analyse the best potential areas for a residential development project and I'm currently doing multi-criteria evaluation. One of the shapefiles in the dataset given is high voltage power lines, I created a buffer around them of 200m (a recommended safe distance) and want to do a Euclidean Distance around that buffer closer being better because of cheaper land value.

Is there a way I can do Euclidean Distance going away from that buffer and not within it?

Should I standardise it, change it into points delete points within buffer then change it back? Seems a bit complex. Please say there's an easier way.

Please forgive me if this is simple my degree isn't GIS!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the spatial analyst extension you can use the Euclidean Distance tool. 
1. Convert the buffer to a raster with the "To Raster" tool (under conversion tools).
2. Then run the Euclidean Distance Tool which will create a raster with values representing distance from the cells that comprised the input raster.
3. Then if necessary, you can extract values from the Euclidean Distance result using something like "Extract Values to Points" tool (which is also in the Spatial Analyst Toolbox). This will allow you to get the distances to any point features occurring near your buffers. There are other ways to extract values but this one should work.